# SAARC countries visited on Indian visa

Tags: visas, india, online-resources

I'm trying to fill out my Indian visa form online and when I get to the SAARC countries visited, I've clicked on Sri Lanka, the year I went and the number of visits, but it won't let me continue, saying that the number of visits is a 'mandatory field'. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What website? When? Looks more like a problem with the site.

Comment: https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html maybe there is a problem, I think I'll have to call them

Comment: I have requested many visas over the years but a recent Indian visa was the hardest by quite a margin.  Harder even than an Iranian visa.  This was partly due to the terrible web application process and partly due to hanging around the embassy for so long.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the rows and then add one again, I ran into the same issue today. Best of luck on your visa application.

Answer (score 0):

Put a best estimate and add a note.

Did you read the instruction? Sometime they have some indication in case of high number of visits, or a temporal period (in last 10 years).

If you cannot trace them (so no stamp on passport), probably also they cannot get it.

Comment: I've read the instructions loads of times and there's nothing. I've only been once so it can't be a high number of visits. There's a stamp on my passport as it was only 18 months ago so it can be traced :(